# Being able to remove duplicate keys from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a question about how I can delete the existing elements, for example, in my case "Tallas" is repeated, could you please help me? Thank you very much to those who are willing to help me to solve this problem

```
const data = 
  [ { atributos: { Tallas:  [{ id: 0, name: 'XS' }, { id: 1, name: 'S'   }] }} 
  , { atributos: { Calzado: [{ id: 0, name: '10' }, { id: 1, name: '9.5' }] }} 
  , { atributos: { Tallas:  [{ id: 0, name: 'XS' }] }} 
  ]
```

The idea is to have this json format with the last "Tallas" since it is the last one that I added through my dynamic form.

```
const expected = 
   [{ atributos: { Calzado: [{ id: 0, name: '10' }, { id: 1, name: '9.5' }] }} 
  , { atributos: { Tallas:  [{ id: 0, name: 'XS' }] }} 
  ]
```

How do I do this is there a way to do it, I've tried with filter plus the findindex but I can't get to eliminate the repetition of the json res= new.filter((arr, index, self) => index === self.findIndex( (t) => (t.attributes === arr.attributes )))

Comment: The central question of this problem concerns comparison of equality of keys/values between 2 objects. This is a difficult problem if you are looking for genericity. If your schema is fixed you can simplify this code. SPV respect the rules of this site: 1) English only, 2) Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand service, where work orders are given and people code for you.

Comment: It is troubling to see that the `id` property apparently does not provide what its name suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unique the array of objects, we can use the Javascript `Set` module, if the array has complex nested objects, we can `stringify` each object before creating new `Set` data. this below function will unique the array of complex objects.

```
function unique_array(array = []) {
     const newSetData = new Set(array.map((e) => JSON.stringify(e)));
     return Array.from(newSetData).map((e) => JSON.parse(e));
}
```

Comment: This would consider `{ id: 1, name: 'S'   }` to be different from `{ name: 'S', id: 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution specific to your question. this is not a generic solution.

```js
const data = [
    {
        atributos: {
            Tallas: [
                { id: 0, name: "XS" },
                { id: 1, name: "S" },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        atributos: {
            Calzado: [
                { id: 0, name: "10" },
                { id: 1, name: "9.5" },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        atributos: {
            Tallas: [
                { id: 0, name: "XS" },
                { id: 1, name: "S" },
            ],
        },
    },
];

function uniqueArray(array) {
    const resultObject = array.reduce((acc, eachValue) => {
        let keys = Object.keys(eachValue.atributos);
        keys.forEach((eachKey) => {
            if (!acc[eachKey]) {
                acc[eachKey] = [];
            }
            let list = eachValue["atributos"][eachKey].map(
                (each) => each.id + "-" + each.name
            );
            acc[eachKey].push(...list);
        });
        return acc;
    }, {});

    const resultArray = Object.keys(resultObject).reduce((acc, each) => {
        let setData = Array.from(new Set(resultObject[each]));
        acc.push({
            atributos: {
                [each]: setData.map((e) => {
                    return { id: e.split("-")[0], name: e.split("-")[1] };
                }),
            },
        });
        return acc;
    }, []);

    return resultArray;
}

const result = uniqueArray(data)
console.log("result ", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```